# Can I connect a MOSFET to an Arduino directly?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, resistors

I have the following [electromagnet](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TOOGOO-Electric-Lifting-Electromagnet-20x15mm/dp/B00HV3N9LG/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1440608539&sr=8-10&keywords=electromagnet) and plan on connecting it to the following [MOSFET](http://uk.farnell.com/nxp/pmn28un-135/mosfet-n-ch-12v-5-7a-sot457/dp/1758105?ost=1758105) which will be controlled by an Arduino (I'm thinking analogue or PWM). Do I need any other parts (resistors etc.) I'm sorry about the vague question but I don't know much about electronics at all and am just starting. By the way, the aim is to be able to control the strength of the electromagnet (12v 300mA-1A) using the Arduino easily.

Comment: You can connect the gate to the MCU output with a current-limiting resistor. Also make sure you have a common ground. But a fail-safe (to some extent) solution would be to use optical isolation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What is the MCU output and what is optical isolation? sorry but as I mentioned in my question I have just started working on electronics

Comment: So probably you should familiarize yourself with the terms first.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well I know what optical isolation is but I don't know how that would be used in this case.. And as far as MCU output is concerned, I am learning on my own and can't find anything on the internet related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect a MOSFET directly, even without a resistor if you like (though it's not nice to put such a heavy load on the output), but if the MOSFET fails with a Drain-Gate short your Arduino will be scrap. I strongly suggest using a **higher voltage MOSFET** than that one- it's only 12V and you will at least be subjecting it to at least 12.5-13V when the MOSFET turns off. It does have nice specs at 4.5V drive (good for an ampere or two), but Vds breakdown is too low.

If you want a modicum of protection, (Edit: Assuming 5V Arduino) put a 5.1V zener on the Arduino output and a 200 ohm metal film resistor to the gate. Put 10K across the 5.1V zener as well so if the output goes open it won't partly turn on.

You **must** put a catch diode across the coil. Something like a 1N5819 would be good. 
Otherwise the MOSFET will get very hot and may fail very quickly.

Edit: You should make sure the MOSFET you select is capable of handling the full current of the solenoid (1A you say).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3j5BR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do these values apply to both the 5V and 3V3 versions? (BTW - the OP does state the current range for the 12V solenoid as 300mA to 1A)

Comment: If I use a higher voltage MOSFET will my Arduino still face the threat of a drain-gate short?

Comment: @RandomUser Yes, it's an inherent risk with non-isolated circuits with mixed voltages. That's why Eugene suggested opto-isolation.

Comment: @JImDearden Okay, edited, thanks. It applies for the 5V version. The knee is too soft on 3.3V zeners to be assured of protection. Maybe use a blue LED capable of 100mA rather than the zener.

Comment: How do you advise I use a catch diode on the electromagnet?

Comment: See above schematic

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you! just one last question regarding your schematic: will PWM or analogue pins be able to control the EM's voltage?

Comment: PWM is appropriate.

Comment: looks good to me +1`

Comment: I found a rectifier diode with the product code you mentioned but not a catch diode.. Do you know where I could find one?

Comment: Catch diode (or flyback diode) refers to the application of the part. The part is a rectifier diode, so you got the right one.